# How much data we can process with in 60 secs In Google App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to fetch a large amount of data from an remote server,for that i am sending a request from GAE  ,As a response  getting a large amount of data in an SOAP Format XML  ,i want to know  How much data we can receive with in 60 secs  In Google App engine ?

Answer (score 1):

The response size should be less than [32MB and within 60 sec](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Quotas_and_Limits). Don't forget that if you're going to hit any of these limits, your application will raise a timeout or something, which is not good.

Most likely you should use the [Task Queue API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or the [deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) to run these tasks in the background and to make sure that the user won't wait 60 seconds before it will time out.

Comment: I have application deployed on GAE. Each endpoint make a connection to database nut some requests are taking more than 60 seconds. So in that case it abort the requests and connections are remaining opened and after some time it starts throwing deadline exceeded error. At that time there are 1000+ connections. how can i solve this ?